# silent writing of file in R, without returning output to console

Tags: r, apply, fwrite

I am using the apply function to write list elements as .csv files to disk:

```
lapply(names(db), function(x) fwrite(db[x],file = paste0(directory, paste0(names(db[x]), ".csv")), row.names = FALSE))
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL
```

but I don't want to see the return in the console - I want it to run silently. How can this be done? I tried the `sapply` and `map`, but return console output.

Comment: try [invisible](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/invisible)?

Comment: Why are you using `lapply`? A `for` loop would be my tool of choice for this.

Comment: `lappy` and `sapply` and `map` all return a value. By default when running interactively, the value that's returned by the last expression is automatically `print()`-ed to the console.  If you aren't trying to return a value, `lapply` is probably the wrong choice. Try something like `purrr::walk` instead. That only does the iteration and doesn't return a value (well, technically, it returns an invisible NULL value)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe (I cannot test, as no file was made available):

```
purrr::walk(names(db), function(x) fwrite(db[x],file = paste0(directory, paste0(names(db[x]), ".csv")), row.names = FALSE))
```